# Expected/Average value of polynomial of uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Lets $X$ be uniformly distributed continuous variable in $[0, k]$. And $f(x)= x^p$. what is the expected value of $f(x)$?

Would it be? $$\int_0^k (\frac{1}{k}) ({x}^p)dx=\frac{1}{k(p+1)}[{x}^{(p+1)}]_0^k = \frac{{k}^{(p+1)}}{k(p+1)} = \frac{{k}^{p}}{(p+1)} ~~~~~ when ~~~~~p ≠ -1~~ .$$

$$\int_0^k (\frac{1}{k}) ({x}^{-1})dx=\frac{1}{k}[ln(x)]_0^k = \frac{1}{k}(ln(k) -\lim\limits_{x \to 0}(ln(x))) = undefined \rightarrow \infty~~~ when ~~~p = -1~~ .$$

Comment: Can you clarify that $X$ is discrete? Otherwise I'm not sure what you mean by "with repetition". Also a large number of draws does not make sense in the case of drawing with repetition, since you will run out of elements to draw.

Comment: @kccu I have modified my question now. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: $(p+1)$ should be on denominator not numerator, otherwise looks ok. In the $p=-1$ case, you can say that the EV is $+\infty$. In either case, be aware that you are using [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)

Comment: @jlammy Thanks for spotting my stupid mistake. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. What you are computing is the $p$th moment.  In general, as [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) says, the $p$th moment of a continuous uniform RV having support $[a,b]$ is

$$\frac{1}{p+1}\sum_{i=0}^p a^i b^{p-i}, $$

with the convention $0^0=1.$

You can see for $a=0,b=k$, you get your result, with the $-1$st moment undefined.